# React - Data from Child to Parent - Issues setting state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure if I'm sending data from a child component to parent component correctly. I'm able to get the data into the parent however whenever I go to set the state in the parent, I get the `Maximum update depth exceeded.` error.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong (new to React):

**Child Component**

So in my child component props - I've added the callback function:

`selectedRowsDataCallback?: (selectedRows: string[]) => void;`

Then later in that child component - in its render, I set some value into it `selectedRowsDataCallback(someOfMyData);`

**Parent Component**

And over in the parent component - I have:

`const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = React.useState([]);`

The child component looks roughly like this:

```
<ChildComponent
   selectedRowsDataCallback={SelectedRowsCallback}
/>
```

And that callback:

```
function SelectedRowsCallback(childData: string[]) {
   React.useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedRows(childData);
   }, [])
}
```

Its at that point get the `Maximum update depth exceeded.` (Of course doing a console.log there I see the data).

So I added the useEffect, with `[]` deps but of course that only gets called once. How do I get it be called each time that child updates?

Anyhow I also have a button on the parent which on clicking I want to get those selectedRows hence I used state to save it.

```
function someButtonAction() {
   // Get from props and do something 
   console.log(selectedRows);
}
```

Any ideas/help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use useEffect in the Parent of Child component?

Comment: In `selectedRowsCallback` yeah I tried that - didn't help - can't be used witihn functions right.

Comment: It would be more easy to debug if you can add code of both parent and child components.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the code from which you call props.selectedRowsDataCallback in child component.

Comment: The code you posted does not have an infinite update loop.Assuming that the child will call selectedRowsCallback when user clicks or changes something then the code you posted so far should work just fine.

Comment: Updated post - added useEffect however not sure how to call each time child component changes

Answer (score 0):

Don't call methods that set the state in the render. What you're doing, if I understand correctly is:

1. you render your Parent which has selectedRows in its state
2. you pass the setter for that state to the Child
3. the child invokes that setter in its render
4. this causes the parent to rerender because the state changes
5. parent rerender triggers child rerender
6. part 3 gets repeated
7. part 4 gets repeated
8. part 5 gets repeated
9. part 3 gets repeated
10. ...

Inside `SelectedRowsCallback` you should check the value of `selectedRows` if it has changed before calling `setSelectedRows`. That should solve this problem.

However, note that whole function is a bit unnecessary since you're creating a new effect every time that only does `setSelectedRows` which is already all you need (+ you should to pass all outer variables to that second argument of `useEffect`)

Additionally, it's a really bad practice to call anything that might trigger a state change inside render, move the `selectedRowsDataCallback` somewhere else - e.g. `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks - however if that function is uncessary, how do I get data from the child to the parent? I thoughts thats the only way.

Comment: The `useEffect` part is unnecessry, you can just call `setSellectedRows` directly and even pass it directly to the child if you're using it like this. The `useEffect` hook is intended to work in a matter where you call it only once and it will call its effect callback on every component update. It is not something you call but something that you pass as a callback to parts of the code which will call it when side-effects need to be done. In your case, the `useEffect` can be used inside the child instead of the `componentDidUpdate` I've mentioned.